# TLS authentication for mosquitto_sub

Tags: ssl, mqtt, tls1.2, mosquitto

I am having some troubles with MQTT authentication via TLS.
I was given this information to access a remote MQTT broker:

- Host
- Port (8883)
- Username
- Password

and I can easily authenticate using GUI clients (like MQTT.FX or MQTTX for windows). In these interfaces, I just have to type the data above and choose "SSL/TLS with CA signed Server". Doing this, everything works even if I initially have no certificates or keys.

I am trying to subscribe to a topic on that broker from Linux CLI using mosquitto_sub, but I can't figure what sequence of operations I should do with certificates to authenticate like MQTTX does.

I tried generating a new certificate and signing it, I tried downloading server certificate and passing it as --cafile, but I am not guessing the right combination of actions, since I always get the following error:

```
OpenSSL Error[0]: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
```

My commands looks like this

```
mosquitto_sub -h mqtt.xxxxxxx.com -p 8883 -i example -V mqttv311 -t mytopic/# --capath /etc/mosquitto/certs -d
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72285557/edit) the question to show the full `mosquitto_sub` command line you are using.

Comment: You need to put quotes round your topic or everything after the `#` will be ignored by the shell. Also have you run `openssl rehash <path to capath>` for the `/etc/mosquito/certs` dir

Comment: Also does the file that has the server cert include the full certificate chain?

Comment: @hardillb actually for my Openssl installation ` 'rehash' is an invalid command`, do I need to install something more?
What I am missing, in general, is how the full certificate chain you mentioned should be obtained, given that all info I have is a username and a password.

Comment: Is the broker cert signed with a public or private CA? If it's a public CA then you should try setting `--capath /etc/ssl/certs`

Comment: @hardillb If I run `openssl s_client -showcerts -servername mqtt.xxxxxx.it -connect mqtt.xxxxxx.it:8883 </dev/null` i can see `Server certificate
subject=/CN=*.xxxxxx.it
issuer=/C=US/O=DigiCert Inc/OU=www.digicert.com/CN=Thawte RSA CA 2018
`

Comment: So a public ca cert. You need to point out at the OS cert store, which is probably where I said it was

Comment: Ok, I see that path exists on my OS (Centos 7). But should I do something for getting all my certificate chain, before I run `mosquitto_sub` with that `--capath`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244878/discussion-between-nicola-fiorello-and-hardillb).